# any tools to show all the objects in my org?

Tags: developer, tools

Is there any tools to show all objects and fields? Everyday I need to go to object managers => list fields in the browser thousands times. Do we have any native application to do this?

Comment: You could use an IDE, or you could even build your own. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: SFDX cli can pull object definitions down. You can also export fields as CSV or download package.xml using these tools: https://cloudtoolkit.co/

Answer (score 1):

[Salesforce inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) chrome extension does wonders for me on a daily basis.  Easily navigate objects and all their fields, what's hidden, updateable, picklist values, and even all the related objects and their API names.  Use it and you'll soon forget what life was without it.

- Note: there are certain orgs / situations where it doesn't work as intended (I'd say maybe one out of every 10 or so), but they also have instructions on how to remedy those situations